# Bean with same name in multiple dependency conflict issue

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, javabeans

New to spring boot.

We have reusable beans in multiple base dependencies. Since, we need those reusable functionality, we are inheriting those jars in pom.xml.

**Ex:**

**Jar1:**

ClassName: UserInfo, RequestInterceptors, ClassName3, ClassName4, ClassNameN.
PackageName: com.somename1.base.comps

**Jar2:**

ClassName: UserInfo,  RequestInterceptors, ClassName3, ClassName4, ClassNameN.
PackageName: com.somename2.base.comps

Since the class name is similar, creates conflict issue, when building.

Unfortunatly, we cannot able to change any class names, since someother teams are using these jar. No permission to create another version of these jars.

Is there any way to include both jar without excluding these conflicting components in `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@ComponentScan`
 annotations?

Could someone share some advice here.

Comment: You might have to do something like `org.something.TextField somethingTextField` and `com.somethingElse.TextField somethingElseTextField`. That's if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score -1):

The solution here would be to name your beans. The reason for the conflict would be that the names of the classes are the same. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class Config{

  public com.somename2.base.comps.UserInfo somename2UserInfo(){
    return new com.somename2.base.comps.UserInfo();
  }
  public com.somename1.base.comps.UserInfo somename1UserInfo(){
    return new com.somename1.base.comps.UserInfo();
  }

}
```

The beans would then be named `somename1UserInfo` and `somename2UserInfo` and you can use these names instead when autowiring, e.g.:

```
public class SomeImpl{

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("somename1UserInfo")
  UserInfo userInfo;

  /*
   * Or you can do this
   */
  @Resource(name = "somename1UserInfo")
  UserInfo theSameUserInfo

}
```

This will allow you to autowire whichever bean should be used in whichever class. It may not be ideal to have to declare a qualifier for every place the classes are used, so if one implementation is primarily used, consider looking into the `@Primary` annotation.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question... You say that this happens when _building_. I don't see how that's possible if the package names are different. Do you mean when running?

Comment: Yes, how its possible if two packages are different from the same class name?

Comment: Resource annotation resolves by name and not type and if this is coming from jar then you cannot change bean name and above solution won't work